# How to decrease png size saved with swift on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, size, png

In my app user can get a photo from the gallery, edit it and then save to documents directory.

Image requirements:
Dimension: 512X512
Size: less when 100Kb

Images basically are WhatsApp stickers

My files are 250Kb+
I already tried a lot, even tried to save files as png8 like this:

```
func normalize() -> UIImage {
        let size = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
        let genericColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: 512, height: 512, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * 512, space: genericColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        context?.interpolationQuality = .default//(thumbBitmapCtxt!, CGInterpolationQuality.default)
        let destRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        context?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: destRect)
        let tmpThumbImage = context?.makeImage()
        let result = UIImage(cgImage: tmpThumbImage!) //, scale: 1, orientation: .up)

        return result
    }
```

this method makes images look bad but size even increased to 300Kb

If anyone knows how to deal with it, please help me.
Please note, I don't need JPEG, I need PNG with transparent background

Also, this may be helpful. In my app, I have a few edit tools, like lasso and eraser. All of them made with `UIGraphicsImageContext` like this:

```
func erase(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(lassoImageView.bounds.size, false, 1)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        lassoImageView.layer.render(in: context!)

        context?.move(to: fromPoint)
        context?.addLine(to: toPoint)
        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(CGFloat(eraserBrushWidth))
        context?.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context?.strokePath()

        lassoImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
```

Maybe something wrong with my `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` implementation?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `250Kb` is a reasonable size for a `512x512` png of a photograph. If they are "basically stickers," do you really need them that big?

Comment: Thank you for respond. Yes, 512 pixels is exact resolution whatsapp sticker should be. As for size, we made stickers with photoshop and were able to make them under 50Kb

Comment: Processing PNGs on the desktop is entirely different than on a mobile device, Photoshop can write in different PNG formats (24BPP or 8 bit color table) and a search of the best compression with different methods can be done. This does not happen on a mobile device.